# Checking when conditional is not a value in ansible

Tags: ansible

I want to run some tasks only if  db_version var is equal or not equal. Here my tasks:

```
- name: Install Software Only 12.1 or 12.2
    shell: |
      {{ stage_dir}}/runInstaller -silent -waitforcompletion \
      oracle.install.option=INSTALL_DB_SWONLY \
      UNIX_GROUP_NAME=dba \
      INVENTORY_LOCATION={{ db_inventory }} \
      ORACLE_HOME={{ oracle_home }} \
      ORACLE_BASE={{ oracle_base }} \
      ..
    when:  db_version == "12.1.0.2" or db_version == "12.2.0.2"

- name: Install Software Only for 18c and above
    shell: |
      {{ oracle_home}}/runInstaller -silent -applyRU {{ stage_dir }} -waitforcompletion \
      oracle.install.option=INSTALL_DB_SWONLY \
      UNIX_GROUP_NAME=dba \
      INVENTORY_LOCATION={{ db_inventory }} \
      ORACLE_HOME={{ oracle_home }} \
      ORACLE_BASE={{ oracle_base }} \
      ...
    when: db_version != "12.1.0.2" or db_version != "12.2.0.2"
```

When db_version is 12.1.0.2 it run the 18c task. What is wrong on this "easy" conditional?

Thanks

Comment: Is it because you have a `or db_version != “12.2.0.2”` instead of `and` on 18c task?

Comment: well tried too with `and` and it run the task.

Comment: `when: db_version != "12.1.0.2" and db_version != "12.2.0.2"` skipped  "Install Software Only for 18c and above" task when `db_version: "12.1.0.2"`.

Answer (score 1):

apparently resolve this issue with version jinja2.

```
when: db_version is version('12.2.0.2','<=')
```

and

```
when: db_version is version('18','>=')
```

In ansible 2.5, ansible rename version_compare to version